# pulling changes from branch pushed to server

Tags: git

I made changes to a git branch on my local machine and pushed the branch to a different machine. Then, I made changes to the branch on this other machine. How do I bring back these changes back to the branch on my local machine?

Comment: If "made changes" means commit+push, just use `git pull`?

Comment: No, the branch on local machine was created from origin/master....after the changes were made, the changes were pushed to a different branch in remote..not to master....when I do git pull, it pulls from origin/master

Comment: update your question with the full details then please

Answer (score 1):

If your updates be in server remote, you just need use command `git pull`. You can see more details about remote branches in this [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)